# Delete property app.config in the project c#/window

Tags: c#

App.config files accidentally deleted . how return it to project

in c# ,window ,wpf

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:Restore**

first check whether file in the recycle bin. if it is there restore it.Go to project select Show all files option in the solution explorer. Then you can see the file. Then right click on App.config and select include in project.

**Option 2: Add new file**

right click on the project and then Add -> new Item

Select general in left side and select Application configuration file and add.